# How to set default card when creating payment intent

Tags: stripe-payments

I can charge a user and save the card for future charges. To set the default card for the user I'm doing `Stripe::Customer.update` (see below)

```
def new
  @payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(amount: 100, 
                                                 currency: 'usd', 
                                                 customer: current_user.stripe_id, 
                                                 setup_future_usage: 'off_session')
end

def create
  @payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve({id: params[:payment_intent_id])
  if @payment_intent.status == "succeeded"
    Stripe::Customer.update(current_user.stripe_id, invoice_settings: { default_payment_method: @payment_intent.payment_method })
        
    #do stuff
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Is there a way to specify that the card being used should be the default for the user when creating the payment intent (instead of calling Stripe again with Stripe::Customer.update)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of a "default" PaymentMethod with PaymentIntents. When creating a new PaymentIntent with a saved card you'd have to specify both the Customer ID and the ID of a PaymentMethod that's attached to the Customer: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-create-payment-intent-off-session